# Changing the origin of a rotation matrix in XNA

Tags: matrix, xna, rotation

I am trying to get 4 Vector2 objects representing the 4 corners of a sprite to rotate around the sprite itself rotates around its center. With my following code, however, the Vector2 objects rotate around 0,0 in Client Space instead of rotating around the center of the object. Using matrix transformations, is there any way to rotate the Vector2 objects around the center of the object instead of the global coordinate (0,0)?

Here is the function for the rotation so far:

```
public Vector2[] CheckCollision()
    {
        //Get the 4 corners of the sprite locally
        //We can get all 4 corners from only 2 vectors
        Vector2 topLeft = new Vector2(position.X - spriteSize.X, position.Y - spriteSize.Y);

        //Not sure why position is representing the
        //bottom right instead of the center here....
        Vector2 bottomRight = position;

        Vector2 bottomLeft = new Vector2(topLeft.X, bottomRight.Y);

        Vector2 topRight = new Vector2(bottomRight.X, topLeft.Y);

        //Create transformation matrix
        Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(this.direction)) *
            Matrix.CreateScale(this.scale);

        //Transform the vectors
        topLeft = Vector2.Transform(topLeft, transform);
        bottomRight = Vector2.Transform(bottomRight, transform);
        bottomLeft = Vector2.Transform(bottomLeft, transform);
        topRight = Vector2.Transform(topRight, transform);

        Vector2[] vectorArray = new Vector2[4];

        vectorArray[0] = topLeft;
        vectorArray[1] = bottomRight;
        vectorArray[2] = bottomLeft;
        vectorArray[3] = topRight;

        return vectorArray;

    }
```

Comment: The fact that your sprite's position corresponds to its bottom right corner leads me to believe that you're specifying an incorrect origin when calling `SpriteBatch.Draw()`.

Comment: @ColeCampbell I specify the center of the sprite as the origin in my `SpriteBatch.Draw()` call. This allows SpriteBatch to rotate the sprite around the center of the object like I am trying to do with the Vector2 objects. I need to fix the position problem as well, but it isn't as severe a problem as my matrix problem, and I feel I can fix it at a later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be a lot easier to just rotate the four corners first before adding the `spritePosition` and add the spriteposition after the rotation and scaling has been performed.

Just make your four corners into the corresponding combinations of `spriteSize` and do the `Vector2.Transform` once that is done add the `spritePosition` to the four vectors in `vectorArray`